# GIT, How to return the list of available remote repositories in the command line?

Tags: git, git-clone

GIT, How to return the list of available remote repositories in the command line? of course, being in the space of one account like: ...?tab=repositories
In other words, choose a repository for cloning without opening the browser. If is it possible.
My question is probably stupid. but actually, the main idea is,
maybe, someone who knows any trick how not leave the command line referring to the list of personal repositories.

Comment: If you are exactly sure on your requirement. This [Q & A](https://superuser.com/questions/379325/is-there-way-to-list-all-existing-repositories-using-git) might help.

Comment: There are probably millions of public repositories in the world which you could clone. Which of them should the command return, and how should it know them?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is lynx

Because the idea was, don't switch from the terminal again and again...
Now, I use the command "lynx", often dive in to,
for copy a path to any repository, as an example
lynx https://github.com/UserName?tab=repositories

It might be useful for those who use the Tmux and Vim.
It is easy to install like:

```
apt -y install lynx
```